# Devolver primer valor no vacio

Tags: excel, filtro, busqueda, excel-2013, excel-2010

Quisiera saber si hay alguna de que la función BUSCARV u otra devuelva el primer resultado no vacío Y/O distinto de 0, es decir si tengo un campo nombre y otro dirección  y nombre se repite 5 veces pero la dirección esta en la 3ra de los 5  como puedo hacer para obtener la dirección de esa tercera fila, si hago solamente buscarv me devuelve vacío por que en la primera fila la dirección está vacía y yo quiero la dirección que esta en la 3ra fila, ocurre lo mismo con índice y coincidir, devuelve la primera fila que encuentra.

**ESTA ES MI TABLA (EJEMPLO)**

```
| Nombre                  | dirección |
| ------------          | -------------- |
| Maria Perez           |                |
| Maria Perez           |                |
| Maria Perez           | León, Nicaragua, Contiguo UNAN|
| Maria Perez           |                |
| Maria Perez           |                |
| Juan Ruiz             |                |
| Juan Ruiz             |                |
| Juan Ruiz             | Managua, Nicaragua, distrito 5 |
```

**Resultado Esperado**

```
| Nombre            | dirección |
| ------------      | ------------- |
| Maria Perez       |León, Nicaragua, Contiguo UNAN|
| Juan Ruiz         |Managua, Nicaragua, distrito 5|
```

He intentado

```
    =BUSCARV([@[Nombre]],Tabla1[Nombre]:[direccion],2)
```

Pero me devuelve vacío por que la primera  coincidencia con el nombre es espacio vacío.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora mismo no caigo en si hay una manera más fácil, pero puedes sacarlo usando SUMAPRODUCTO con operadores dobles unarios y la función ÍNDICE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[SUMAPRODUCTO (función SUMAPRODUCTO)](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/sumaproducto-funci%C3%B3n-sumaproducto-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

[INDICE (función INDICE)](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/indice-funci%C3%B3n-indice-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)

[Operador doble Unario](https://es.switch-case.com/3286197)

En la captura de pantalla he dividido la fórmula en 2 partes para explicarlo mejor pero es perfectamente posible combinar todo en una sola fórmula.

SUMAPRODUCTO nos devuelve, en combinación con el operador unario, matrices de 1 y 0 según se cumplen condiciones. En la celda E2 mi fórmula es:

```
=SUMAPRODUCTO(--($A$2:$A$16=D2)*--($B$2:$B$16<>"")*FILA($B$2:$B$16))
```

Desglosemos la fórmula:

1. `--($A$2:$A$16=D2)` esto devolverá una matriz de 1 y 0 dependiendo de si las celdas de la columna A (campo nombre) son iguales a lo que estoy buscando en la celda D2. Siguiendo nuestro ejemplo, esta parte devolvería: `{1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
2. `--($B$2:$B$16<>"")` Esto devuelve 1 y 0 dependiendo de si las celdas de la columna B (campo dirección) están vacías o no. En nuestro caso, esta parte devolvería `{0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
3. `--($A$2:$A$16=D2)*--($B$2:$B$16<>"")` Es simplemente multiplicar las dos matrices anteriores, es decir, `{1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} * {0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} = {0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`. Es importante señalar que, si te fijas, esta matriz ya contendrá un solo 1, que representa la **posición** donde se encuentra la dirección.
4. `FILA($B$2:$B$16)` devuelve una matriz que contiene el número de fila de cada elemento, es decir, `{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21}`
5. Multiplicamos las matrices de los pasos 3 y 4 entre ellas y obtenemos el resultado deseado. Siguiendo nuestro ejemplo `{0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} * {2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21} = {0;0;4;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}`
6. Finalmente, SUMAPRODUCTO suma todos los valores que hay en la matriz anterior, que son todo ceros menos el número de fila que tiene la dirección que buscamos y nos devuelve un 4

Ahora vamos con la formula en F2. Yo tengo puesto `=SI(E2=0;"No encontrado";INDICE($B$2:$B$21;E2-1))`. Primero comprobamos que el resultado de SUMAPRODUCTO no sea cero, porque eso significaría que no existe ese elemento. En caso de que sí exista, simplemente recuperamos el valor. Es importante destacar que restamos 1 porque el nº de fila obtenido es referenciado a la hoja de Excel, es decir, incluyendo la fila 1, pero la matriz de datos empieza en la fila 2 en esta función, así que para ajustar hay que restar -1.

Como puedes ver en la imagen, funciona perfectamente. Y la formula final fusionada en una sola celda sería así:

```
=SI(SUMAPRODUCTO(--($A$2:$A$16=D2)*--($B$2:$B$16<>"")*FILA($B$2:$B$16))=0;"No encontrado";INDICE($B$2:$B$21;SUMAPRODUCTO(--($A$2:$A$16=D2)*--($B$2:$B$16<>"")*FILA($B$2:$B$16))-1))
```

Un saludo.